# What is the correct form in this case?

Tags: verbs, past-tense

The example I gave in my comment below is a different one but this is what I was trying to do actually.
I was writing down this narrative that happened many years ago, like 10 years or so. I am saying about a particular day from 10 years back.

I wrote like this :

*When I was a kid, I had many toys, but the toy train was my favourite. 
That year too I demanded another toy train for my birthday present as few days back the previous toy train **had got broken**. So my father bought this new one. I was very happy. But on this very fateful day, I broke the new one too.*

This is where  I am getting confused. 
I want to say that the toy was broken accidentally just few days before that fateful day. I didn't break it intentionally or consciously.

I feel like if I use 'The toy **was broken**',  then the reader would think that somebody broke the toy because of some reason, which is not the case.

Same I feel with 'The toy **had been broken**'

It sounds odd to me if I say 'The toy **got broken**' or 'The toy **had got broken**'

So I am really confused about what to use here. 
Hope I explained properly this time.

Comment: Hello, Spectra, and welcome to ELL!  I'm sorry you were unable to edit your question before.  I've unlocked this copy of the question so you can edit it with the details you've been asked for, if you wish.  We can probably get it reopened on this site if you edit this copy of the question :-)  The copy on English.SE is probably not going to be reopened, so I suggest editing here, not there.

Comment: @snailplane :Thank you for unlocking this one. I understood the reason behind it getting closed, so I am editing only here. I am really sorry for all the mess. :) Hope I did everything right this time :)

Comment: "When I was a kid, I had many toys, but my favorite was my toy train. That year, I asked for another toy train for my birthday as the old one had broken a few days prior, so my father bought a new one. I was very happy. But on this very fateful day, I broke the new one, too." That's how I would have written this sentence. And my advice, stay away from toy trains :D.

Comment: This is better!!  :) Since I never got another toy train, I am kinda staying away from those ever since. :D

Comment: @Spectra Nice. Just as an aside, in case you cared (which I assume you do since you're actively participating on this site), I would have said, "Well, since I haven't gotten anymore toy trains since (then), I have kinda been staying away from them (ever since)", that is, I would have used present perfect to show continuity. What do you think?

Comment: Is "haven't gotten" okay to use ? "haven't got" comes easy to me. Like : 
Since I haven't got anymore toy trains since......

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A few days back, the toy *broke*.

> To emphasize the event.
>
> Usually implying that it had broken on its own.
>
> Sometimes just used to tell the story of what had happened after.

A few days back, the toy *was* broken by someone, somehow.

> To emphasize the event.
>
> Probably because you want to place blame.

A few days back, the toy *was* broken.

> To emphasize the state of the toy.
>
> As the listener, I would generally expect the follow-up to be, "But it's not broken now" right after the above sentence.

A few days back, the toy *had been* broken.

> To emphasize the state of the toy again.
>
> However, this time, as the listener, I'm left in suspense about the state of the toy *now*. So my follow-up now would now, "And now? Is the toy still broken now?"

The reason you're having trouble is because you should use passive voice here, not "got."

Hopefully, this also helps you hear the difference between having used the simple past and past perfect.

Comment: I have a question with  this one :
"A few days back, the toy had been broken."

Doesn't it mean that someone broke the toy intentionally ?

Comment: @Spectra And no, it does not imply intention. It's only describing the state of the toy a few days ago. The whole thing is ambiguous. Which is why we use passive voice, usually. "The toy had been broken." "By whom?" "I don't know." "Where?" "I'm not sure." "When?" "Good question." "Then, what DO you know?" "The toy had been broken." ".... Is it still broken now?" "I don't know." "!!!!"

Answer (score -2):

You yourself have answered your question, 
"want to mean that the ***toy got broken*** accidentally few days ago"

The tense is of past indefinite. Therefore, "got broken" would be correct.

> Few days back, the toy *got broken*.

Comment: Not so. OP's "context" isn't even a complete sentence, and it certainly gives us no indication of the contextual ***narrative time***. I don't much like the usage, but syntactically, *The toy had got broken long before I decided who to give it to for Christmas* is fine.

Comment: @FumbleFingers 
There's nothing more to the sentence I originally posted. I want to use it in a situation like this : 
My friend : Show me the toy I gave you.
Me : Oh, sorry, The toy 'had got broken'/ 'got broke' few days back.

Comment: This is where I'm getting confused to use what

Comment: @Spectra: You should include that additional context in the question, not tucked away in a comment. Note that although someone else has edited your ungrammatical text to make a valid sentence, that doesn't give any clue as to the relevant "narrative time". Your comment here makes it obvious there's no justification for using Past Perfect, since you're *not* talking about some event in the past that *precedes* some other past event that you're actually talking about.

Comment: @FumbleFingers : So, do I need to edit the question and add that example ? I tried now but the edit link is not working.

Comment: Oh! That's strange! I see this post has been ***locked** by the special automated "pseudo-user" (called *Community* here on Stack Exchange). That looks to me like a mistake, because even *you* can't edit the question (after which people might decide to to allow vote to ***re-open*** it). I will ask about this on the [ELL meta](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/) site, and perhaps our site moderators will unlock it. Please check back again later.

Comment: ...[here's](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/3364/community-user-locks-post-preventing-user-from-making-clarifying-edits) my meta question, if you want to see what others have to say.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Ok, I will come back later and check. Thanks for looking into the matter :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Does narrative time matter in this case? I feel like she should have said "A few days ago, the toy broke." I feel like "got" shouldn't even have appeared in this sentence.

Comment: @Teacher KSHuang: I too don't think much of "got-support" in this exact context, but the Simple Past / Past Perfect issue would be exactly the same with A: *Show me the toy.* B: *Oh, sorry, The toy **had been** broken*. In any context I can conceive of, that would always need to be something like *The toy **has been** broken / **is** broken*, or perhaps ***was** broken*. Past Perfect would require something like B: *Oh, sorry, The toy **had been** broken **before you even gave it to me.***

Comment: @Spectra: I don't know if you've seen the replies to my question about this on ELL meta, but apparently the reason you can't edit *this* instance of the question is because it was [originally posted on our sister site ELU](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/364915/). You should be able to edit *that* version - but to be honest I doubt that ELU users would then vote to reopen, because they'll probably think it's *still* not the right kind of question for that site. I'm sorry if this isn't very helpful to you, but please don't be put off using ELL for any future questions you may have.

Comment: @FumbleFingers : Yes I have seen your post and other replies on ELL meta. I understood the reasons behind all this and am sorry for all the mess I created. Thanks for helping with unlocking the post :)

Comment: Hmmm, I feel like the example sentence you give changes the meaning a bit, @FumbleFingers. That is, if the OP had given the same example as you give in your comment, I would change my answer.

Comment: @Teacher KSHuang: Back when you posted this answer, OP hadn't supplied *any* examples or context. Which per my initial comment makes it completely meaningless to speculate whether Past Perfect would *actually* be appropriate or not. I should also add that I don't think "Past Indefinite" is a valid (or even, *meaningful*) label in the context of English.

Comment: @FumbleFingers All I'm saying is that at the time that you had left your example sentence, OP had already supplied OP's own example sentence and that the two feel different to me.